Returned object destroyed when *this is returned from function call on temporarily constructed object
I have this code where the I call member functions on a temporary object of Test class
not production code: https://godbolt.org/z/8YW7EqEf6
    const auto &t2 = Test().withT1().withT2();
    testParam(t2);

With the above function calls to withT1 and withT2 the temporary object gets destroyed immediately. And, a destoryed object (t2) is sent to the function testParam
However, if I do not call the member functions withT1 and withT2 the temp object, it is assigned correctly to reference variable t2, and holds it lifetime until end on block scope.
not production code: https://godbolt.org/z/9hEanEeGY
Can someone please help me understand why the compiler behaves this way?

Lifetime extension only works when binding directly to a const reference. It cannot be passed on.

Interesting, can you please share some references from the c++ standard about this, and post this as an answer. I'll mark it as answered. Thanks.

Sorry, don't have a formal reference. Just something I have learned.

You can find the list of all cases where it is passed on here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime (it propagates through some operators, but not function calls).

How should the compiler know that the temporary object that begins with Test() is the same one referenced by the return value of the final .withT2()? In general, these can be different objects. Hence, there is no rule to extend the lifetime of some, any, or all, random temporary objects that occur in a complex expression. Only particular ones are extended: those that bind directly to the reference.

This is a valid argument. @j6t
I was just wondering, if this behaviour is documented or open for compilers to implement.

@51k it's not a quote from the formal spec, but the link that HolyBlackCat posted in the comment above pretty much gives you the answer. It contains a list of all cases where lifetime is extended, and your case isn't in it.

The behaviour is certainly documented by the standard.  The standard's purpose is to constrain implementations (compilers and libraries), not to be organised for easy interpretation by C++ developers/coders who use an implementation. The link given by HBC summarises relevant parts of the standard, in (relatively) more readable form.   Relevant clauses may well be sprinkled in various sections/paragraphs of the standard, not in a consolidated form so, with enough effort and masochism, you or some language lawyer could find all the section/para references, but most mere mortals don't bother.
